# how can i get null value from Stored procedure sql 2008 server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have created a SP in sql 2008 its working fine when i execute it it showing the out put but i want that if record are not in table then it will show the 0 or Null values in all columns.

its working fine in simple select query but when i call store procedure it not showing any thing.

```
   Alter proc [dbo].[catewiseexp] @awpyear varchar(50) =null ,
    @divisionid int=null
    As
    begin 
    declare  @res as numeric(18,2) =null

    select 
    /* Financial Progress  C1    */
    isnull(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),sum(CASE WHEN awpyear=@awpyear and cateid=1 THEN (IDA)/100000 ELSE 0 END)),0) as ReIDA,
    isnull(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),sum(CASE WHEN awpyear=@awpyear and cateid=1 THEN (Govt)/100000 ELSE 0 END)),0) as ShStat,
    isnull(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),sum(CASE WHEN awpyear=@awpyear and cateid=1 THEN (Benyfe)/100000 ELSE 0 END)),0) as BeneContro,
    isnull(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),sum(CASE WHEN awpyear=@awpyear and cateid=1 THEN (IDA+Govt+Benyfe)/100000 ELSE 0 END)),0) as Total,
    /* Financial Progress C2     */
    isnull(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),sum(CASE WHEN awpyear=@awpyear and cateid=2 THEN (IDA)/100000 ELSE 0 END)),0) as ReIDA2,
    isnull(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),sum(CASE WHEN awpyear=@awpyear and cateid=2 THEN (Govt)/100000 ELSE 0 END)),0) as ShStat2,
    Isnull(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),sum(CASE WHEN awpyear=@awpyear and cateid=2 THEN (Benyfe)/100000 ELSE 0 END)),0) as BeneContro2,
    isnull(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),sum(CASE WHEN awpyear=@awpyear and cateid=2 THEN (IDA+Govt+Benyfe)/100000 ELSE 0 END)),0) as Total2,
    /* Financial Progress NR     */

COALESCE(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),sum(CASE WHEN awpyear=@awpyear and cateid=0 THEN (Govt)/100000 ELSE 0 END)),0) as NR,

/* Financial Progress  Total IDA     */
isnull(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),sum(CASE WHEN awpyear=@awpyear THEN (IDA)/100000 ELSE 0 END)),0) as TotIDA,

/* Financial Progress tot State Share   */
isnull(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),sum(CASE WHEN awpyear=@awpyear and cateid<>0 THEN (Govt)/100000 ELSE 0 END)),0) as TotStat,

/* Financial Progress tot State Share with NR  */
Isnull(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),sum(CASE WHEN awpyear=@awpyear THEN (Govt)/100000 ELSE 0 END)),0) as TotStatNR,

/* Financial Progress Beneficiary Contro     */
isnull(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),sum(CASE WHEN awpyear=@awpyear THEN (Benyfe)/100000 ELSE 0 END)),0) as TotBenyfe,

/* Financial Progress total    */
isnull(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),sum(CASE WHEN awpyear=@awpyear THEN (IDA+Govt+Benyfe)/100000 ELSE 0 END)),0) as TotFin


from AWP
where  Division=@divisionid 
group by Division
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this...  we firstly check if there are any records for the division and if not, we select zeros

```
Alter proc [dbo].[catewiseexp] @awpyear varchar(50) =null ,
@divisionid int=null
As
begin 
declare  @res as numeric(18,2) =null

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM AWP WHERE Division=@divisionid) 

  select 
  /* Financial Progress  C1    */
  isnull(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),sum(CASE WHEN awpyear=@awpyear and cateid=1 THEN (IDA)/100000 ELSE 0 END)),0) as ReIDA,
  isnull(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),sum(CASE WHEN awpyear=@awpyear and cateid=1 THEN (Govt)/100000 ELSE 0 END)),0) as ShStat,
  isnull(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),sum(CASE WHEN awpyear=@awpyear and cateid=1 THEN (Benyfe)/100000 ELSE 0 END)),0) as BeneContro,
  isnull(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),sum(CASE WHEN awpyear=@awpyear and cateid=1 THEN (IDA+Govt+Benyfe)/100000 ELSE 0 END)),0) as Total,
  /* Financial Progress C2     */
  isnull(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),sum(CASE WHEN awpyear=@awpyear and cateid=2 THEN (IDA)/100000 ELSE 0 END)),0) as ReIDA2,
  isnull(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),sum(CASE WHEN awpyear=@awpyear and cateid=2 THEN (Govt)/100000 ELSE 0 END)),0) as ShStat2,
  Isnull(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),sum(CASE WHEN awpyear=@awpyear and cateid=2 THEN (Benyfe)/100000 ELSE 0 END)),0) as BeneContro2,
  isnull(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),sum(CASE WHEN awpyear=@awpyear and cateid=2 THEN (IDA+Govt+Benyfe)/100000 ELSE 0 END)),0) as Total2,
  /* Financial Progress NR     */

  COALESCE(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),sum(CASE WHEN awpyear=@awpyear and cateid=0 THEN (Govt)/100000 ELSE 0 END)),0) as NR,

  /* Financial Progress  Total IDA     */
  isnull(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),sum(CASE WHEN awpyear=@awpyear THEN (IDA)/100000 ELSE 0 END)),0) as TotIDA,

  /* Financial Progress tot State Share   */
  isnull(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),sum(CASE WHEN awpyear=@awpyear and cateid<>0 THEN (Govt)/100000 ELSE 0 END)),0) as TotStat,

  /* Financial Progress tot State Share with NR  */
  Isnull(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),sum(CASE WHEN awpyear=@awpyear THEN (Govt)/100000 ELSE 0 END)),0) as TotStatNR,

  /* Financial Progress Beneficiary Contro     */
  isnull(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),sum(CASE WHEN awpyear=@awpyear THEN (Benyfe)/100000 ELSE 0 END)),0) as TotBenyfe,

  /* Financial Progress total    */
  isnull(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),sum(CASE WHEN awpyear=@awpyear THEN (IDA+Govt+Benyfe)/100000 ELSE 0 END)),0) as TotFin

  from AWP
  where  Division=@divisionid 
  group by Division
else
  select 
  /* Financial Progress  C1    */
  0 as ReIDA,
  0 as ShStat,
  0 as BeneContro,
  0 as Total,
  /* Financial Progress C2     */
  0 as ReIDA2,
  0 as ShStat2,
  0 as BeneContro2,
  0 as Total2,
  /* Financial Progress NR     */
  0 as NR,
  /* Financial Progress  Total IDA     */
  0 as TotIDA,
  /* Financial Progress tot State Share   */
  0 as TotStat,
  /* Financial Progress tot State Share with NR  */
  0 as TotStatNR,
  /* Financial Progress Beneficiary Contro     */
  0 as TotBenyfe,
  /* Financial Progress total    */
  0 as TotFin

end
```

Comment: Can you perhaps mark the question as answered then?